# Inserir tupla de dados na mesma célula do banco de dados

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Possuo o seguinte script:

```
import pymysql

cobertura = (10, 20)
base_de_dados = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "senha", "base_de_dados")
cursor = base_de_dados.cursor()
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO individuo VALUES (NULL, %s)", (cobertura))
base_de_dados.commit()
base_de_dados.close()
```

Quando executo, invés de os valores (10, 20) serem salvos como tuplas em minha base de dados, eles são gravados em linhas diferentes.
Por exemplo, o valor 10 na coluna 1 linha 1 e o valor 20 na coluna 1 linha 2.

Como faço para que os valores sejam salvos como tuplas na mesma célula?

Grato aos que puderem me ajudar!

Comment: Você quer salvar no banco a *string* `(10, 20)`?

Comment: Exatamente isso @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Tente colocar uma vírgula após o `cobertura`: `(cobertura,)`. Sem ela, o Python não define uma tupla, mas sim utiliza os parenteses para controlar as precedências da expressão. Com a vírgula ele entenderá que o que quer fazer é criar uma tupla.

Comment: Editei dessa forma o código: cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO individuo VALUES (NULL, %s)", (cobertura,))

Apresentou o erro: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Então precisará converter a tupla para *string*: `(str(cobertura),)`

Comment: Complicado assim. A mensagem diz que o conteúdo foi truncado, então provavelmente você definiu a tabela de forma errada. Qual o tipo e comprimento da coluna `cobertura`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, primeiramente desculpa, a solução que você passou : Então precisará converter a tupla para string: (str(cobertura),).

Funcionou corretamente, eu havia esquecido de modificar o tipo de dado na minha tabela para VARCHAR.

Muito Obrigado!

Não quer postar como resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro inicial é na forma que está passando o valor para a função. Quando você faz `(cobertura)` você não está criando uma tupla, pois assim o Python interpreta apenas que os parenteses são para controlar a precedência de operadores na expressão. Prova disso, basta você verificar o comprimento da tupla:

```
print len( (cobertura) ) # 2
```

O resultado será 2, respectivo aos valores 10 e 20 em cobertura. Isto é, fazer `(cobertura)` é o mesmo que apenas `cobertura`. Para criar uma tupla com o valor da variável, você precisa inserir uma vírgula após seu nome:

```
(cobertura,)
```

Com a vírgula, o Python passa a entender que você quer criar uma nova tupla com o valor de `cobertura`. Mas outro ponto é que a tupla não será convertida para *string* automaticamente. Será necessário convertê-la manualmente:

```
(str(cobertura),)
```

Assim, considerando que o banco de dados esteja devidamente configurado, funcionará como desejado.